# Replacing lines with single quote and other special characters in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to replace certain lines in several txt documents that might be in subfolders or the current folder. Some of the lines include characters like ' and parenthesis are giving me problems. The lines will repeat multiple times in each file.

This line seems to work

```
ls *.txt -rec | %{$f=$_; (gc $f.PSPath) | %{$_ -replace " in chips\)", ")"} | sc $f.PSPath}
```

this one also works

```
ls *.txt -rec | %{$f=$_; (gc $f.PSPath) | %{$_ -replace [regex]::Escape("won ("), "won "} | sc $f.PSPath}
```

but this one i cant make it work

```
ls *.txt -rec | %{$f=$_; (gc $f.PSPath) | %{$_ -replace ":  Hold'em No Limit ($0.50/$1.00 USD)", " - Holdem(No Limit) - $0.50/$1.00"} | sc $f.PSPath}
```

I have tried with \ before the parenthesis putting the text i want to find with [regex]::Escape() but nothing has worked so far.

What am i missing in order to achieve this?

Bonus problem:

The next problem that i also haven't figured out is that i need to remove both opening and closing parenthesis from a line but has to keep them in other part of the line so for example:

Original line:
Seat 5: WTFWY (big blind) won ($17.10)

Wanted output
Seat 5: WTFWY (big blind) won $17.10

I was trying to look for "0)" and "won (" and replace them that way, but the "0)" part could be any number and there has to be a more elegant way to do it than to do one for each number with parenthesis. Any ideas for this?

Comment: If you want to replace strings literally, why not use a replacement method that replaces literally? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-7.0

Comment: Dollar signs within double quotes will get interpreted as variables.  You can escape a single quote with another single quote.  This is a common quoting question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- As a general rule in **PowerShell**, only use double-quoteed strings
  when you need the capabilities of an expansion string.
- You can use the `[Regex]::Escape()` method on any string you want to match literally.
- As an alternative to escaping quotation marks within strings, I find here-strings are easier to read and I don't have to remember how to escape quotes.
- Replacement text is usually literal, but can reference the groups in the `$matches` variable created when the regex is matched, using the format `$<Group#>` in the replacement string. To specify a literal `$` as a replacement character, use `$$`.

So, for your first problem string:

```
$find = [Regex]::Escape(@'
:  Hold'em No Limit ($0.50/$1.00 USD)
'@)

$replace = ' - Holdem(No Limit) - $$0.50/$$1.00'

@'
Special:  Hold'em No Limit ($0.50/$1.00 USD) - Limited Time
'@ -replace $find , $replace
```

Output:

```
PS > $find = [Regex]::Escape(@'
>> :  Hold'em No Limit ($0.50/$1.00 USD)
>> '@)
>>
>> $replace = ' - Holdem(No Limit) - $$0.50/$$1.00'
>>
>> @'
>> Special:  Hold'em No Limit ($0.50/$1.00 USD) - Limited Time
>> '@ -replace $find , $replace
>>
Special - Holdem(No Limit) - $0.50/$1.00 - Limited Time
PS >
```

For the Bonus question:

1. Escape a sample of the text you want to replace:

   - `[Regex]::Escape('($17.10)')` ==> `\(\$17\.10\)`
2. Replace literal dollar digis with a match for one or more digits - `\d+` and the decimal digits with a match for exactly two digits - `\d{2}`:

   - `\(\$\d+\.\d{2}\)`
3. Use parentheses to define the amount won as a capture groups:

   - `\((\$\d+\.\d{2})\)`
4. Test the matching:

   ```
   PS > 'Seat 5: WTFWY (big blind) won ($17.10)' -match '\((\$\d+\.\d{2})\)'
   True
   PS > $matches

   Name                           Value
   ----                           -----
   1                              $17.10
   0                              ($17.10)
   ```
5. Execute your replace operation:

   ```
   PS > 'Seat 5: WTFWY (big blind) won ($17.10)' -replace '\((\$\d+\.\d{2})\)' , '$1'
   Seat 5: WTFWY (big blind) won $17.10
   PS >
   ```

---

---

MOre than one way to skin a cat...

Another way to deal with your first string would be to focus only on the text you wish to modify by chaining together two replacement operations. THe first to modify `:  Hold'em` and the second to modify `($0.50/$1.00 USD)` as we did in the bonus question:

```
@'
SPecial :  Hold'em No Limit ($0.50/$1.00 USD) - Limited Time
'@ -replace ":  Hold'em" , ' - Holdem' -replace '\((\$0\.50/\$1\.00) USD\)' , '$1'
```

Ooutput:

```
PS > @'
>> SPecial :  Hold'em No Limit ($0.50/$1.00 USD) - Limited Time
>> '@ -replace ":  Hold'em" , ' - Holdem' -replace '\((\$0\.50/\$1\.00) USD\)' , '$1'
SPecial  - Holdem No Limit $0.50/$1.00 - Limited Time
PS >
```

But actually, `($` at the beginning and `USD)` at the end are enough to distinguish your targeted substring, and so we can simplify to:

```
@'
SPecial :  Hold'em No Limit ($0.50/$1.00 USD) - Limited Time
'@ -replace ":  Hold'em" , ' - Holdem' -replace '\((\$.+) USD\)' , '$1'
```